# Is there a more formal way to say 氆氇?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a more formal way to say 氆氇?

For example:

> 你的衣服上掉了饼干渣，氆氇一下。
>
> There are some biscuit crumbs on your shirt,  get them off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

掸一掸 Dan3 Yi1 Dan3

A special tool for it is 鸡毛掸子 Ji1 Mao2 Dan3 Zi

Answer (score 3):

```
氆氇（pǔlu 〖藏pulu〗）是藏族人民手工生产的一种毛织品，可以做衣服、床毯等，举行仪礼时也作为礼物赠人。
```

I don't think native speakers would say this word. "get them of" simply means 弄掉它们.

Comment: Maybe 扑落, 扑落扑落脏

Answer (score 2):

给/把 construction with 掉 as the resulting "disposal" condition is probably the most natural yet neutral way to express this. E.g. 给它们抖掉。

You may want to also refer to the action on the clothes rather than on the crumbs, which would allow a more specific direct object. E.g. 把衣服抖一下。